# Accessing AWS S3 folder name in unicode using AWS command line util

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Due to my ignorance, I named a folder on S3 in unicode a few years ago. I'm able to list objects without spaces easily, but I can't access any files/folders with spaces. I've tried delimiting the space with a `\`, but it didn't work.

Example folder path:

`s3://my-folder/a-thing/إلى آخره`

Command looks like:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-folder/a-thing/إلى\ آخره
```

Comment: Enclose the entire `s3://...` URI in `'` single quotes?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Still nothing.

Comment: Perhaps the space isn't a `0x20` space?

Comment: I tried a space from both keyboards. How would I represent it on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape the space, you need to add the delimiter before the space, not after. Additionally, the key of the object you are looking at ends in a `/` so you need to include that or add `--recursive`. So your particular command should look like this:

```
> aws s3 ls s3://folder-object/another/إلى \آخره/
2015-10-15 09:36:20          0 إلى آخره/
2015-10-15 09:37:40        152 إلى آخره/somefile.txt
```

Comment: It is added before the space, it looks like it wasn't because the writing is automatically switched from right to left with Arabic. I tried both ways and also added the end '/', but it still didn't work.

Comment: What output are you seeing? I created a 'folder' with that exact name, put an object underneath, ran the command listed, and it worked. Are you using a current version of the CLI (`aws --version`)?

Comment: aws-cli/1.7.6 Python/2.7.10

Comment: It worked, I was trying with single quotes as per someone else's advice. A delimiter is not necessary with single quotes.